# Django and NoneType object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I have such model:

```
class Body(models.Model):
    point = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank = True)
```

When I am adding in django admin interface a new record I am getting

'NoneType' object is not callable

with TemplateSyntaxError message. So, record is successfully created but I can't see the list of records in django admin panel.

http://dpaste.com/hold/152729/ this is the link to the traceback from django

What should I do?

Comment: The message includes a specific line of code and (generally) a stack traceback.  Can you provide the traceback?  Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: This only happens when you add a new record or also if you want to list the records directly?

Comment: Yes. It happens when I want to list my records and when I want to add a new record.

Comment: set DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=True in settings and try again, that'll give more info on issue

Comment: I have found the solution. :) When I've changed 'order' name to something else I've got no error messages. :) Thanks all for your attention to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that

```
order = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank = True)
```

was the reason of my problem. When I've changed 'order' name to something else I've got my problem fixed. :)

Comment: well that's weird. Could you post full model and admin classes somewhere please?

Comment: I had the same problem with an attribute called "save". I guess these words are already reserved by the django model.